# How do I make this pthread sleep for milliseconds instead of seconds?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

timespec m_timeToWait;
pthread_mutex_t m_lock;
pthread_cond_t m_cond;

timespec & calculateNextCheckTime(int intervalSeconds){
    timeval now{};
    gettimeofday(&now, nullptr);
    m_timeToWait.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + intervalSeconds;
    //m_timeToWait.tv_nsec = (1000 * now.tv_usec) + intervalSeconds;
    return m_timeToWait;
}

void *run(void *){
    int i = 0;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m_lock);
    while (i < 10) {
        std::cout << "Waiting .." << std::endl;
        int ret = pthread_cond_timedwait(&m_cond, &m_lock, &calculateNextCheckTime(1));

        std::cout << "doing work" << std::endl;
        i++;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_lock);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    int ret;
    int i;
    std::cout << "In main: creating thread" << std::endl;
    ret = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &run, NULL);
    pthread_join(reinterpret_cast<pthread_t>(&thread), reinterpret_cast<void **>(ret));
    return 0;
}
```

There are similar examples on SO, but I can't seem to figure it out. Also, the Clion IDE insists that I use re-interpret casts on the pthread_join params, even though examples on SO don't have those casts in place. I am using C++11.

Comment: You could use `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(...))` or better `sleep_until` if you are checking at a fixed interval. Why use the C interface to `pthread` instead of the C++ standard `std::thread` class? Are you using a pre C++11 compiler (but tagged it c++11 by mistake)?

Comment: As this is tagged `c++11` why not make use of [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) and associated mutex/condition_variable types?

Comment: I just noticed that you commented out the use of `tv_nsec` in `struct timespec`. Why? With nanoseconds you should be able to do your `pthread_cond_timedwait` will millisecond precision (or very close).

Comment: The code base is 20+ years old, so there are all kinds of thread implementations. I tried to use `std::thread` but it kept core dumping. It wasn't clear from the core file what caused it, so I took this known working example from another part of the code.

Comment: Why did you comment out the line that gives you subsecond timing? If you want subsecond timing, that seems like a strange choice.

Comment: "_I tried to use `std::thread` but it kept core dumping_"  - Any program with undefined behavior may do so. You may have used the language incorrectly. There are a few examples of similar loops at SO that uses `std::thread` successfully, so don't think core dumps are inherent.

Answer (score 0):

This is just maths.

You have access to `tv_sec`, and you have access to `tv_nsec`.

- Currently you're only setting `tv_sec`, to "the seconds part of *now*, plus *X* seconds".
- You can also set `tv_nsec`, to "the nanoseconds part of *now*, plus *Y* nanoseconds".

The result is "now, plus *X* seconds and *Y* nanoseconds"… which is when you want the program to wait (at the earliest), with nanoseconds resolution.

Just uncomment the line that does this, then provide the appropriate numbers for what you want to do.

You could have the function take an additional "milliseconds" argument (don't forget to multiply it by 1,000,000!) then leave the "seconds" at zero if you want that:

```
timespec& calculateNextCheckTime(const int intervalSeconds, const int intervalMillis)
{
    timeval now{};
    gettimeofday(&now, nullptr);
    m_timeToWait.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + intervalSeconds;
    m_timeToWait.tv_nsec = (1000 * now.tv_usec) + (1000 * 1000 * intervalMillis);
    return m_timeToWait;
}
```

You may or may not wish to perform some range checking (i.e. verify that `intervalMillis >= 0 && intervalMillis < 1000`) to avoid nasty overflows.

Or, instead, you may wish to allow `calculateNextCheckTime(1, 234)` to be treated the same as `calculateNextCheckTime(3, 34)`. And that will work, but only because you're also going to need to implement "carry" semantics to ensure that `m_timeToWait.tv_nsec` is less than 1,000,000,000 after adding the `(1000 * now.tv_usec)` component, over which the calling user has no control. (I have not implemented that in the above example.)

Also, you may or may not wish to make those arguments `unsigned`.

Comment: I think tv_nsec has to be less than 1 000 000 000, so if it's greater than that, you have to subtract a billion nanoseconds and add one second.

Comment: @user253751 I said that ;)

Comment: @user253751 I suggested range checking (though that could be left as a precondition instead). I suggested adding carry semantics so the calling scope doesn't have to care (but that's optional). What more do you want...?

Comment: No matter how much you range-check *`intervalMillis`*, `(1000 * now.tv_usec) + (1000 * 1000 * intervalMillis)` could be more than a billion.

Comment: @user253751 .......... oh yeah. :) Me done an edit.

Comment: Also there are 1000 milliseconds in a second, not 100

Comment: @user253751 Don't bring facts into this 

Comment: Thanks for you answer. If I set `intervalMillis` to 1000, I would expect to see a 1 second pause between, `Waiting` and `doing work`. Equally if I set it to 100, I would expect to see a 100ms pause. I don't see either. It doesn't pause for any length of time.

Comment: @eeijlar: Is that having made the suggested change? Have you done `pthread_cond_init` somewhere? Show your [mcve].

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: code is as posted in the original question with the following changes based on your suggestions:   `m_timeToWait.tv_sec = 0;` and `m_timeToWait.tv_nsec = (1000 * now.tv_usec) + (1000 * 1000 * intervalMillis);`. I am not using the seconds part. I have not done `pthread_cond_init`

Comment: @eeijlar: _"I have not done pthread_cond_init"_ Why not?